# How to create an extension command similar to VSCode's File: New File command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to create a command that has the same flow where once you create the command it will take you to the explorer window and allow you to type the name of the file there. Is there a way to do that with the existing vscode API?

Update: The flow of creating the file through the explorer was done by executing 'explorer.newFile'. I want to take the user's input, create 2 template files, and then delete the original file created by 'explorer.newFile'. It does not seem like 'explorer.newFile' returns info about the new file so I created a filewatcher to do this which makes for choppy creation/deletion of the files. Is there a way to make this smoother?

Answer (score 1):

No, not as VSCode 1.15. Your best bet currently is to either try reusing the built-in create file command (`explorer.newFile`) or to use the quick picker API to achieve a similar flow

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by reusing the built-in create file command? Do you mean going into the source for vscode and seeing if I can reuse that? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Try using the built-in `explorer.newFile` command. When fired, it will trigger the same flow as creating a new file using the explorer. I've added a note on this

Comment: Thanks, that helped get the flow down. Unfortunately it does not look like the command's promise resolves to a value that info about the file created. I want to create 2 files based on the user input and then delete the file created by explorer.newFile. To do this, I've set up a filewatcher on created files and will get the file info that way but this makes the creation/deletion very slow. Any suggestions? I will update the question with more specifics.